# Why is Keras not using the full GPU memory?

Tags: keras, out-of-memory, gpu

I am a new Keras user, so sorry if this is a rookie question. It seems like I have an artificial limit that is preventing me from using the full GPU memory, but my config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction is not set to have any limit. Does anyone know what else might be preventing me from using the full memory? I will explain why I think I am prevented from using the full memory below.

I have a pretty large Keras model with a Tensorflow backend that I am running on AWS. I can train with batch_size 4, but if I train with batch_size 8 it overflows memory. My instance is a p3.2xlarge that has 16 GB of GPU memory, and I have verified that it is using the GPU from the K.tensorflow_backend._get_available_gpus() command.

I tried upgrading to a p3.8xlarge, which has 4 times as much GPU memory (64 GB). I was expecting that I could train the same model with a much larger batch size after doing this. Everything that I am reading online shows that the most important aspects of memory consumption are linear in batch_size. But it still overflows memory with I use a batch_size of 8.

Does anyone know why I might not be getting access to my full GPU memory, of if there is anything else I could check to debug what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just realized what my problem was. The added memory on the new node is split across 4 GPUs, and in order to access them you need to use the keras.utils.training_utils.multi_gpu_model, as explained here: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/10/30/how-to-multi-gpu-training-with-keras-python-and-deep-learning/

I tried this out and it solved my issue.